# SSH IP access restriction using tcpwrappers is not working. (hosts.allow and hosts.deny not taken into account)

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I am using sles-12 server and i am trying to restrict ssh access to my server to my pc alone. I have tried to use tcpwrappers and it's not working..!!. I am able to ssh to the server from any IP in my local network.

I have tried different formats from man page to see if anything is working but to no effect. Here is the files I have used for setting the wrappers and commands which might be useful

```
[root@myserver ~]# cat /etc/hosts.allow
sshd:172.19.112.120
[root@myserver ~]# cat /etc/hosts.deny
sshd:ALL
[root@myserver ~]#  tcpdmatch -d -i /etc/xinetd.conf sshd 135.250.164.106 --> another server
client:   hostname paranoid
client:   address  135.250.164.106
server:   process  sshd
access:   granted  --> NOT OK
[root@myserver ~]#
[root@myserver ~]# ldd /usr/sbin/sshd | grep 'libwrap'
        libwrap.so.0 => /lib64/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007fa2b71f7000)
```

PS: IP table restrictions are working fine. But I can't use it in my scenario. and no specific configurations are done in /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: I have found the problem on why it's not working. I am using openssh v 7.2 and tcpwrappers support is removed from openssh from version 6.7 onwards.  Link --> https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html (Check release notes of version 6.7).

Answer (score 0):

Infact we can do it with sshd_config file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

I used the parameter Allowusers in format AllowUsers admin@ and it worked fine. We can add more users or IPs as per need.

Reference: https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config